# formulate a power series

Tags: summation, estimation

Could anyone advise me if there is any way to estimate/formulate the following series

$$
\sum_{i=m..n} \left(\frac{c}{i}\right)^i
$$

where m,n and c are positive integers.

Comment: What do you mean with $i=m\ldots n$?

Comment: Is the sum over the finite set $\{m, m+1, \ldots, n\}$?

Comment: yes, I meant  finite set {m,m+1,…,n} and a m is relatively big.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a better estimate, but I can get an upper bound to be $e^c$ as follows
$$ \sum_{i=m}^n\dfrac{c^i}{i^i}\leq \sum_{i=m}^n\dfrac{c^i}{i!}\leq e^c.$$

Of course this is assuming you mean the sum from $m$ to $n$, and this upper bound becomes a very bad estimate as $m$ grows.